# How can i make my curl command work in gitlab-ci?

Tags: powershell, docker, curl, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have curl that i use in gitlab-ci job to upload an artifact to Nexus
the command is as follow (defined in .gitlab-ci.yml under script section)

`cmd /c curl -v -u $env:USERREG:$env:PASSREG --upload-file $env:BINFILE $env:NEXUS_REGISTRY/$env:REPONAME$env:BINFILE`

of course all the variables are declared in .gitlab-ci.yml file except for USERREG and PASSREG which i declared them using the gitlab GUI.

Notice that i am using:
- Gitlab Runner with docker-windows executor 
- Windows docker container to exec the above command

PROBLEM : the job is stacked demanding for the user (defined by USERREG) password (PASSREG) until the job is terminated due to timeout.

How to fix this problem ? thank you.

Comment: the msg shown is ` Enter host password for user 'some name`:

Comment: are you using basic auth on nexus?

Comment: yes , i use basic auth

Comment: could be an escape problem. your password has special characters? try to write the password directly on this job

Comment: i have base64 password, and i did test directly the password

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this could be your problem, but please check and refer to the GitLab Variables which you set ( USERREG and PASSREG). If they are protected variables that means that they will be only available on a "protected" branches and in case you are pushing it from non-protected branch that could brings you to the state where you are currently because above mentioned variables are not available.

If this is the case, just make them to not be protected but masked and you should be fine.